# Moving through plotly graphs

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using plotly to graph some data and i'd like to add some arrows to the right and the left to move forward and backward through the data. if there is no such solution, what other libraries would you recommend that implement this feature? I know it is possible to expand both axes but I would like to make it more user friendly/intuitive.

Comment: https://plot.ly/javascript/sliders/

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Close enough, although I wonder if there is a better way.